# Should istream be passed as reference or const reference?

Tags: c++

Should istream be passed as reference or const reference?

I only need to extract the string from the istream, and not modify
the istream in any way. Is there a reason why not to pass it as
const reference if I don't plan to modify it?

Comment: Extracting from it does modify it.

Comment: Whenever you read from `istream`, it updates the pointer so the next read comes from the next value within the stream. If you defined it as a `const`, the pointer is unable to be modified appropriately.

Answer (score 5):

Usually streams are passed by non-const references.  This is because most useful operations, like insertion (write) and extraction (read) do actually modify the stream state.  With a const reference all you can really do is inspect the existing state, such as the error flags.